# Strange Behavior with PHImageManager when request Image Data for a PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am creating a basic image editor that takes an image and applies basic metadata changes. After applying any edits, I use a `PHAssetChangeRequest` to submit the edits to the photo library.

My understanding is that in doing this I am not modifying the original media but creating a new `PHAssetResource`.

I can confirm that my edits are working and new `PHAssetResources` are being added to the `PHAsset`. See below for logs.

Why is it that when I request image data for this asset (after modification has occured) I am given the original asset even when requesting with `options.version = .current`.

Closing the app and restarting it seems to correct this behavior and the very same function returns the correct, modified image data from that point onward. By doing this, the app completely reloads all the assets from the photo library. But this shouldn't affect the requesting of actual image data from assets.

Is there a way to force the `isCurrent` property of the asset resources or is there something I am otherwise missing?

```
 ///Loads the photos data using a completion handler
    func getPhotoData(photo: Photo, reflectingEdits: Bool = true, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?) -> ()){

        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.version = .original

        if(reflectingEdits){
            options.version = .current
        }

        manager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: photo.asset, options: options, resultHandler: {
            data, uti, orientation, info in

            print("Succesfully delivered image (\(String(describing: uti))) -> \(data?.count ?? 0) bytes")

            completionHandler(data)
        })
    }
```

**Before**

```
[<PHAssetResource: 0x28328eb50> {
    type: video_cmpl
    uti: com.apple.quicktime-movie
    filename: IMG_0067.MOV
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B.MOV
    width: 980
    height: 1308
    fileSize: 2403227
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: OriginalVidCompl
    isCurrent: YES
}, <PHAssetResource: 0x283281dd0> {
    type: photo
    uti: public.heic
    filename: IMG_0067.HEIC
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B.HEIC
    width: 3024
    height: 4032
    fileSize: 1331238
    analysisType: never-download
    cplResourceType: Original
    isCurrent: YES
}]
```

**After**

```
[<PHAssetResource: 0x28329d320> {
    type: adjustment
    uti: com.apple.property-list
    filename: Adjustments.plist
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Mutations/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B/Adjustments/Adjustments.plist
    width: 0
    height: 0
    fileSize: 7129
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: Unknown
    isCurrent: NO
}, <PHAssetResource: 0x28329d440> {
    type: video_cmpl
    uti: com.apple.quicktime-movie
    filename: IMG_0067.MOV
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B.MOV
    width: 980
    height: 1308
    fileSize: 2403227
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: OriginalVidCompl
    isCurrent: YES
}, <PHAssetResource: 0x28329cfc0> {
    type: photo
    uti: public.heic
    filename: IMG_0067.HEIC
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B.HEIC
    width: 3024
    height: 4032
    fileSize: 1331238
    analysisType: never-download
    cplResourceType: Original
    isCurrent: YES
}, <PHAssetResource: 0x28329d170> {
    type: photo_full
    uti: public.jpeg
    filename: FullSizeRender.jpg
    asset: 8B5B03FE-9862-4DD9-BB81-C9753FDE328B/L0/001
    locallyAvailable: YES
    fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Mutations/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group125/5571C124-DF27-4636-9AFC-23786A33850B/Adjustments/FullSizeRender.jpg
    width: 4032
    height: 3024
    fileSize: 2036693
    analysisType: unavailable
    cplResourceType: JPEGFull
    isCurrent: NO
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by manually requesting the appropriate resource using `PHAssetResourceManager`.

I can't find any documentation to prove my theory but my guess is that when performing a `PHAssetChangeRequest`, the new `PHAssetResource` is not set as current immediately. Or perhaps there is some action like the instantiation of the `PHImageManager` class that updates what resources are set to current.

I used `PHAssetResourceManager.requestData...` to retrieve the `PHAssetResource` with the specific `type` property/properties I wanted. It's not as simple as the original method, this time split into two different functions, but it means I don't rely on the mercy of the PHImageManager to decide the relevant resource to fetch.

```
    ///Loads the edited photos data using a completion handler
    private func getEditedPhotoData(photo: Photo, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?) -> ()){

        if let editedPhoto = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: photo.asset).first(where: {$0.type == .fullSizePhoto || $0.type == .alternatePhoto}){
            PHAssetResourceManager.default().requestData(for: editedPhoto, options: nil, dataReceivedHandler: completionHandler, completionHandler: {
                error in

                if(error != nil){
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            })
        }else{
            completionHandler(nil)
        }

    }

    /// Loads the photos original data using a completion handler
    private func getOriginalPhotoData(photo: Photo, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?) -> ()){

        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.version = .original

        manager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: photo.asset, options: options, resultHandler: {
            data, uti, orientation, info in
            completionHandler(data)
        })

    }
```